# javascript : TypeError: this.jalsonicBroMajorVersion.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to check is **jalsonicBroMajorVersion** have value or not. if jalsonicBroMajorVersion have spaces on it i am use replace function for it.

**javascript:**

```
jalsonicBroMajorVersion = "";
jalsonicBroMajorVersion = abc['Information']['jalsonicBroMajorVersion'];
jalsonicBroMajorVersion = jalsonicBroMajorVersion.replace(/\s+/g,"");

if (jalsonicBroMajorVersion == "")
{
  console.log("empty'");
}
else
{
   console.log("value'");
}
```

when i run this code terminal give me this error

> TypeError: jalsonicBroMajorVersion.replace is not a function

Comment: What scope are you in / what's `this`? What's in abc['Information']['jalsonicBroMajorVersion']?

Comment: sure you want the quotes in second line around `jalsonicBroMajorVersion ` ? Not enough code shown to replicate your problem. We have no idea what `abc` is

Comment: `this` type by mistake ... abc is array

Comment: i am define abc like this `var abc = {};`  and assign values `abc.Information.jalsonicBroMajorVersion = "helloworld"`

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: Problem is solved. :)